# Finding a probability distribution function from a density function of two variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The following problem is on page 249 of the book "Mathematical Statistics with Applications". The number of the problem is 6.22. Below is my attempt to solve it. However, my answer is wrong. I want to know where I went wrong.
Thanks,
Bob

Problem:
The joint distribution for the length of life of two different types of components operating in a system was given in Exercise 5.10 by:
$$ f(y_1,y_2) = \begin{cases}
\left( \frac{1}{8} \right) y_1 e ^{-\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}} & \text{for } y_1 > 0; y_2 > 0 \\
0 & \text{otherwise }
\end{cases} $$
The relative efficiency of the two types of components is measured by $U = \frac{Y_2}{Y_1}$. Find the probability density function for $U$.
Answer:
Now to find the density function, we first find the distribution function and differentiate.
\begin{align*}
P(U <= u_0 ) &= \int_0^{\infty} \, \int_{0}^{u_0 y_1} \left( \frac{1}{8} \right) y_1 e ^{-\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}} \, \, dy_2 \, dy_1 \\
P(U <= u_0 ) &= \int_0^{\infty} \, -\frac{y_1 e^{ -\frac{(y_1+y_2}{2} }}{16} \bigg|_{0}^{y_2 = u_0 y_1} \, dy_1 \\
P(U <= u_0 ) &= \int_0^{\infty} \, - \frac{ y_1 e^{ -\frac{(y_1+uy_1)}{2} } } {16 } + \frac{ y_1e^{ \frac{-y_1}{2} } } {16 } \, dy_1 \\
16 P(U <= u_0 ) &= \int_0^{\infty} \, y_1e^{ -\frac{y_1}{2}} dy_1 -
\int_0^{\infty} \, y_1 e^ { - \frac{(y_1 + uy_1)}{2 } } dy_1
\end{align*}
Using an online integral calculator, I find that:
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \, y_1e^{ -\frac{y_1}{2}} dy_1 = 4 $$
Now we want to perform the second integral. We rewrite this integral as:
$$  \int_0^{\infty} \, y_1 e^ { - \frac{(u+1)y_1}{2 } } dy_1 $$
From a table of integrals we have:
$$ \int xe^{ax} \, dx = \frac{e^{ax}}{a^2} ( ax - 1) + C $$
So we apply this integral with $a = -\frac{(u_0+1)}{2}$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\infty} \, y_1 e^ { - \frac{(u_0+1)y_1}{2 } } dy_1 &=
\frac{e^ { - \frac{u_0+1}{2} y_1} } { \frac{(u+1)^2}{4} } \left( \left( \frac{-(u_0+1)}{2 }\right)y_1 - 1 \right)  \bigg|_{0}^{\infty} \\
\int_0^{\infty} \, y_1 e^ { - \frac{(u_0+1)y_1}{2 } } dy_1 &=
0 - \frac{1}{ \frac{(u_0+1)^2}{4} } \left( 0 - 1 \right) = \frac{4}{(u_0+1)^2} \\
16 P(U <= u_0 ) &= 4 - \frac{4}{(u_0+1)^2} = \frac{4(u_0+1)^2 - 4}{(u_0+1)^2} \\
4 P(U <= u_0 ) &= \frac{(u_0+1)^2 - 1}{(u_0+1)^2}  = \frac{u_0^2 + 2u_0 + 1 - 1}{(u_0+1)^2} \\
P(U <= u_0 ) &= \frac{u_0^2 + 2u_0 }{4(u_0+1)^2} \\
F_u(u) &= \frac{u^2 + 2u }{4(u+1)^2} 
\end{align*}
Now to find the density function $f_u(u)$ we differentiate.
\begin{align*}
f_u(u) &= \frac{4(u+1)^2(2u+2) - (u^2 + 2u)(2)(4)(u+1)}{16(u+1)^4}  \\
f_u(u) &= \frac{4(u+1)(2u+1) - (u^2+2u)(8)}{16(u+1)^3} = \frac{(u+1)(2u+1) - 2(u^2 + 2u)}{4(u+1)^3} \\
f_u(u) &=  \frac{2u^2 + 2u + u + 1 - 2u^2 - 4u}{4(u+1)^3} \\
f_u(u) &= \frac{-u + 1}{4(u+1)^3} \\
\end{align*}
However, the book gets:
$$ \frac{2}{(1+u)^3}, \,\,\, u > 0 $$
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Check your algebra!  $P(U\le u)=\frac{u^2+2u}{4(u+1)^2}\to \frac{1}{4}$ as $u\to \infty$ is wrong, since it should $\to 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two simple errors.
$\frac{1}{16}$ should be $\frac{1}{4}$ after the first integration..
The algebra for $f_u(u)$ should end up as $f_u(u)=\frac{1}{2(u+1)^3}$
(The second line $(2u+2)$ was changed to $(2u+1)$).

Correcting for these errors leads to $f_u(u)=\frac{2}{(1+u)^3}$